# Adding annotations into an existing rdf file

Tags: python, rdflib

I would like to add triples into an existing rdf file. I am trying following code but it erases all the previous content before adding specified triples.

```
imparse.add((rdflib.term.URIRef(im),OWL_NS['sameAs'],rdflib.term.URIRef(ep)))
imparse.commit()
imparse.serialize(destination='foaf.rdf',format='xml')
```

Could you please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you didn't parse (read) the file into imparse before serializing:

```
from rdflib.graph import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse("foaf.rdf", format="xml")
```

For more info on this i suggest the getting started in the [docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/rdflib/en/latest/).